# How to render a native WebComponent inside an Vue mounted app ONLY ONCE

Tags: javascript, web-component, vuejs3

I created a native web-component(`CampusList`) which will request server.
Because I put it inside an element mounted by Vue, therefor Vue will `createElement`of that web-component second time
[image]
Because that component will require data from server, it will send the same request twice!
Of course it should not, what should I do?

Comment: Don't render the content inside ``CampusList``. Built all your elements (in a DIV or whatever) then at the end do ``CampusList.replaceWith(div)``

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the fetch to only happen once (even if you have multiple instances of the element on the page) you could declare a variable inside the custom element import, but outside of the definition, and check it before you fetch. In that way the fetch will only happen the first time it's encountered e.g.:

```js
let fetchMade = false;

class CampusList extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    if (!fetchMade) {
      console.log('fetch!');
      fetchMade = true;
    } else {
      console.log('do not fetch');
    }
  }
}

customElements.define('campus-list', CampusList);
```

Comment: Therefor I need to do so repeatedly many times in many classes? Personally I think it's not that clear/simple